# Plupload uploadprogress event always giving file.percent as 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, progress-bar, plupload

I am using the *plupload.full.js* downloaded from the http://www.plupload.com for uploading images.

My issue is when I tried to display a progress bar using the upload progress event it always gives a value 100 only. Is this an issue? How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: please post relevant code (client-side and server side). have you tried with file sizes which triggers chunking ?

Comment: I have the same issue. @RobinAT Did you figure it out?

Comment: instead of plupload i used another custom script for uploading, but that will not work in IE < version 6

Comment: It depends on the uploaded size of the content.

Comment: @Robin Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to upload large image size file see the snapshot

[image]

```js
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes : 'html5,flash,silverlight,html4',
     
    browse_button : 'pickfiles', // you can pass in id...
    container: document.getElementById('container'), // ... or DOM Element itself
     
    url : "https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/upload",
     
    filters : {
        max_file_size : '10mb',
        mime_types: [
            {title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"},
            {title : "Zip files", extensions : "zip"}
        ]
    },
 
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plupload/2.3.6/Moxie.swf',
 
    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : '/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
     
 
    init: {
        PostInit: function() {
            document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML = '';
 
            document.getElementById('uploadfiles').onclick = function() {
                uploader.start();
                return false;
            };
        },
 
        FilesAdded: function(up, files) {
            plupload.each(files, function(file) {
                document.getElementById('filelist').innerHTML += '<div id="' + file.id + '">' + file.name + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(file.size) + ') <b></b></div>';
            });
        },
 
        UploadProgress: function(up, file) {
            document.getElementById(file.id).getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = '<span>' + file.percent + "%</span>";
        },
 
        Error: function(up, err) {
            document.getElementById('console').innerHTML += "\nError #" + err.code + ": " + err.message;
        }
    }
});
 
uploader.init();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plupload/2.3.6/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plupload/2.3.6/moxie.js"></script>

<div id="filelist">Your browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight or HTML5 support.</div>
<br />
 
<div id="container">
    <a id="pickfiles" href="javascript:;">[Select files]</a>
    <a id="uploadfiles" href="javascript:;">[Upload files]</a>
</div>
 
<br />
<pre id="console"></pre>
 
 
<script type="text/javascript">
// Custom example logic
 

</script>
```

Comment: I've tried with 20Mb+ files and still has the same issue.

Comment: the limit is 10mb have you changed max_size in filter..?

Comment: in my code it will result in error 200 bacause it needed that upload method to upload the file. So try to use that filter.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your last comment? I can hardly understand it, sorry.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see what I was typing I have updated my comment

Comment: Sorry, but your solution does not give answer the original issue.

Comment: I don't know how you are getting this issue... but i have work on pulpload extensively but I never have such kind of scenerio